why my i cant display my kotlin code on console
i am new at kotlin and i am just keeting started with the basics, whenever i try to run a simple task like println("something") android studio throws error Default Activity not found
how can i display my code in console and not in the virtual machine
i cant find a solution even in kotlin official site

Android Studio is an IDE for Android App Development. If you want to build a basic Kotlin application, try another IDE like IntelliJ
